# stop and play in radio button in android

Tags: android, radio-button

i have 2 mp3 files in the raw folder. I am trying to show the audio files in the radio button.if i click radio button i want to play the audio.and if choose another radio button old audio should stop,new audio should play. This is my code.in my code audio is playing but when i choose another audio app is quitted.

thanks in advance 
     options.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Add Background" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/music1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Music1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/music2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/music1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:text="Music2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/music1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Self Speach" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

```
  public class OptionActivity extends Activity {

 RadioButton myOption1, myOption2, myOption3,myOption4;
 MediaPlayer mp,mp1;


  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.options);
      myOption1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
      myOption2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.music1);
      myOption3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.music2);
      myOption4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
      setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      myOption1.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);
      myOption2.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);
      myOption3.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);
      myOption4.setOnClickListener(myOptionOnClickListener);
      myOption1.setChecked(true);
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.airtel);
      mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.airtelbird);
  }
  RadioButton.OnClickListener myOptionOnClickListener =
   new RadioButton.OnClickListener()
  {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if(myOption1.isChecked())
      {

          myOption2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          myOption3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            /*  int resId;
              switch (v.getId()) {
              case R.id.music1:
                //resId = R.raw.airtel;

                break;
              case R.id.music2:
                 //resId = R.raw.airtelbird;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
              default:
                //resId = R.raw.airtel;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
              }*/

      }
      if(myOption4.isChecked())
      {

          myOption2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          myOption3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }

      if(myOption2.isChecked())
      {
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         mp.start();
         mp1.release();

      }

      else if(myOption3.isChecked())
      {      
          mp1.start();
         mp.release();

      }


    }


  };
}
```

This is my error log

```
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561): Process:   com.example.videoapp, PID: 9561
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):   java.lang.IllegalStateException
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._getAudioStreamType(Native Method)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.getAudioStreamType(MediaPlayer.java:1363)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.isRestricted(MediaPlayer.java:1347)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1336)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at com.example.videoapp.OptionActivity$1.onClick(OptionActivity.java:89)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5181)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:128)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20887)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
   06-05 12:44:31.060: E/AndroidRuntime(9561):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may customize radio button to look like stop button when not selected and look like play when selected and handle functionality in button click handler.
You need to use radio button group for this.
Let me share code

```html
 <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_1"

        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_2"

        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_3"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"

        android:background="@drawable/radio_button"

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

I am using custom radio_button.xml

```html
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/regular_state"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/regular_state"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_state" />
</selector>
```

My selected_state.xml Please modify according to your use case, add image for play

```html
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000" />
</shape>
```

My regular_state.xml

```html
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#880000" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..i shared my xml code also.i couldn't understand your layout

Comment: I dont know how to use these XML

Comment: @VinodhKumar As I have shared the code, in radio buton set android:background="@drawable/radio_button"
        Add radio_button.xml under drawable folder as shared.
In it, we are using 2 custom layouts for pressed and normal state

Comment: @VinodhKumar Add selected_state.xml and normal_state.xml in drawable  folder and define layout of button in it as you want in pressed and normal state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79753/discussion-between-vinodh-kumar-and-nitish516).